# timestamp to text

Tags: javascript, date, web, calendar, timestamp

I wanted to know if there's a javascript library which can convert timestamp (Date java class value) to text.
for example:

1. two minutes ago
2. 4 hours ago
3. 23 Aug 2009

is this kind of library exist? otherwise I'll implement it by myself of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to try momentjs which helps you parse time formats. Take a look at http://momentjs.com/

Heres some sample codes:
 moment().format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); 
moment().format('dddd [on the] wo [week of the year]'); 
moment().format("MMM Do 'YY"); moment().format();

This library is helpful and easy to learn.